# Best recommendation for converting vector files to gcode for Next Wave CNC

Tags: cad

I am using [VCarve Pro](https://www.vectric.com/free-trial/vcarve-pro) with a [Next Wave Shark HD 510](https://nextwavecnc.com/product/shark-hd510/).  It works fine but I would like to consider some open source alternatives as well.  I mainly use it to convert vector files to gcode. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I tossed "inkscape vector to gcode" into my search field and the returns were overwhelming. There's an extension that is either default installed in Inkscape or easily added that covers conversion.

It's not intuitive (to me) but the number of tutorials that cover the process should encompass your requirements. One of the more [attractive tutorials](https://forums.maslowcnc.com/t/inkscape-for-gcode-generation-quick-instructions-to-get-started/12049) references the Maslow CNC machine, which is primarily aimed at the hobbyist and would likely simplify the explanation of the process necessary to accomplish your objective. Image below from linked site:

[image: inkscape vector to gcode image]

Comment: Thank you @fred_dot_u for the response.

Comment: @SteveC Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).